# Is Google App Engine's level of support robust enough for real-world production?

Tags: google-app-engine

Google App Engine has been great for trying out ideas and learning stuff, but so far I haven't seen much confidence in the community in using it for production applications.

One significant issue that has come up over and over again is that when things go wrong, it's nearly impossible to actually talk to anyone at Google. This is really scary if your company is depending on this service for the production app.

However, their [literature on Premier accounts](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/premier/index.html) looks promising, with the promise of better levels of support.

What has been your experience with using Google App Engine when it comes down to resolving support issues? Does it really take 4 hours to just acknowledge a P1?

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to real-world production, I don't think it's a matter of support in this case.

I think what's keeping off most people is the tight coupling with appengine API and datastore architecture. You have no hands on it, and are at the mercy of Google will, if they change anything, you'll probably need to rewrite things.

Whereas the competition is more SOA's friendly, you do everything yourself.

GAE provide so many thing out of the box that it's perfect for a lonely dev, but I don't think it fits a company needs and future-proofing that well.

If you want a recent example, just look at the amount of dissatisfaction from the way Google handled the appengine end of preview.